# ORA-00904: invalid identifier - No encuentra el valor asignado en el mapeo de la clase

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, struts2

El proyecto se realiza con Struts 2 e hibernate con hql sin jpa. Al haber cambiado librerias de hibernate y la versión de java me encuentro con el fallo de que teniendo la clase asignada al mapeo con el fichero xml que conecta con una tabla de bbdd, ahora no permite usar los parametros asignados, los da como no válidos con el error: **ORA-00904: "NOMBREgrupo": invalid identifier**

mapeo xml con la tabla:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class
    name="com.gr.group.ui.dtoimpl.GroupImpl"
    table="HTKD.TUGROUP">

    <id name="id" column="COD_id" type="java.lang.String">
    </id>

    <property name="NOMBREgrupo" type="java.lang.String" update="true"
        insert="true" column="DES_NOM" />
        
    <property name="paisdes" type="java.lang.String" update="true"
        insert="true" column="DES_PAIS" />
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Clase del objeto:

```
package com.stercomm.customers.bbva.agrupacion.ui.dtoimpl;

  import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.Date;
  import com.gr.group.ui.dtoimpl.GroupImpl;
  import com.gr.group.ui.dtoimpl.BaseHibernateBeanImpl;

 public class GroupImpl extends BaseHibernateBeanImpl implements
      GMMFileAgrupacion {

private String id;
private String NOMBREgrupo;
private String paisdes;


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNOMBREgrupo() {
    return NOMBREgrupo;
}

public void setPaisdes(String NOMBREgrupo) {
    this.NOMBREgrupo = NOMBREgrupo;
}

public String getPaisdes() {
    return paisdes;
}

public void setNOMBREgrupo(String paisdes) {
    this.paisdes = paisdes;
}
}
```

DAO:

```
 public ResultMeta<GroupImpl> getGropu_name_files(String NOMBREgrupo,String paisdes) {

    Session session = getHibernateSession();
    
    List<GroupImpl> listaAgrupados =new ArrayList<GroupImpl>();
    Query queryCount;
    

        sqlConsulta = " FROM GroupImpl agrup where NOMBREgrupo = 'ficheroDos' and paisdes = 'ES'";
        
        
  [..........................]

    return rm;
}
```

Y tras hacer los cambios de librerias para adaptarlo, no me reconoce los nombres que le asigno a los campos de la tabla, les tengo que poner directamente los nombres de las tablas para que funcionen.